# Apache выставляет для загруженных файлов права 700, как мне изменить это на 770?

Tags: php, linux, apache

Apache выставляет для загруженных файлов права 700, как мне изменить это на 770?

Comment: chmod() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.chmod.php

Comment: Вы хотите переопределить поведение по умолчанию?

Comment: https://php.ru/manual/function.umask.html

Answer (score 0):

если в php, то можно проверить установленный, затем изменить если не тот.

```
if(file_exists($file))
{
     $check =  substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($file)), -4); 
     if($check != '0770')chmod($file, 0770);
}
```